# Imagem sempre no topo ao receber o efeito hover

Tags: html, css

Estou desenvolvendo um site com CSS e HTML, mas enfrento um problema. 
Tenho uma parte desse site como espécie de galeria, e quando uma imagem recebe `hover`, ela fica maior. O problema é que ela fica embaixo das outras, como na print no fim do post.

```
/* Grow */
.hvr-grow-shadow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  position: relative;
}
.hvr-grow-shadow:hover, .hvr-grow-shadow:focus, .hvr-grow-shadow:active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.8);
  transform: scale(1.8);
  position: relative;
}
```

CSS:

```
<center><img class="hvr-grow-shadow" src="img/thumbs/asun.png" style="margin-left:2%;'">
<img class="hvr-grow-shadow" src="img/thumbs/bigode.png" style="margin-left:2%;">
        <img class="hvr-grow-shadow" src="img/thumbs/bradesco.png" style="margin-left:2%;"></center>
<br>
<center><img class="hvr-grow-shadow" src="img/thumbs/parobe.png" style="margin-left:2%;">
        <img class="hvr-grow-shadow" src="img/teste3.png" style="margin-left:2%;">
        <img class="hvr-grow-shadow" src="img/teste3.png" style="margin-left:2%;"></center>
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defina um `z-index`, abaixo:

```
.hvr-grow:hover, .hvr-grow:focus, .hvr-grow:active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.8);
  transform: scale(1.8);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Sem sucesso amigo.

Comment: Aqui funcionou sem `z-index` e com.

Comment: Estou com chrome no windows 10, sem sucesso. Continua em baixo

Comment: Esses quadrados 200x200 que você desenhou aí é o que ?

Comment: Uma img qualquer só porque não tinha o que colocar.

Comment: O nome da classe não está batendo com o nome da classe na imagem.

Comment: Onde? Em que parte?

Comment: Nome da classe no CSS `hvr-grow`. Nome da classe na tag `img` => `hvr-grow-shadow`.

Comment: Realmente, mas mesmo assim adicionei no hvr-grow-shadow e não funcionou igual

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q3xm2tv0/

Comment: Resolvi adicionando position: absolute; e z-index: 10; no hvr-grow-shadow.

Comment: O seu código não está funcionando @Zoom -> https://jsfiddle.net/q3xm2tv0/1/ coloquei as bordas.

Comment: @MucaP veja minha resposta.

Comment: Cara, mas você colocou o `z-index: 10;` que eu falei ? Eu coloquei aqui e funcionou. Veja bem... https://jsfiddle.net/q3xm2tv0/2/

Comment: @CelsomTrindade, sua resposta é igual a minha, não mudou absolutamente nada...

Comment: @Zoom a explicação foi diferente e o seu fiddle não funcionava.

Answer (score 1):

Você está utilizando o nome da classe de modo errado, o seu `css` está definido como `hvr-grow` e o seu `html` está como `hvr-grow-shadow`. Basta remover o `-shadow` do seu `html` e tudo vai funcionar.

Depois, para corrigir o problema do `:hover`, basta adicionar a propriedade `z-index:1`, deste modo a `img` em `:hover` ficará sempre 1 nível acima das demais.

Lembrando que para que a propriedade `z-index` funcione, é necessário que você tenha a propriedade de `position` definida. Porém, como ela já foi definida na classe .hvr-grow, não há necessidade de duplicar a definição no estado de `:hover`, uma vez que você não está manipulando este comportamento.

```
.hvr-grow:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.8);
    transform: scale(1.8);
    z-index:1;
}
```

Veja um exemplo funcionando: https://jsfiddle.net/z16usfps/